# In hashmap , set custom object value with in place object instantiation

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I am creating a HashMap with custom object (say Employee) as key. 
**I have no modification access to Employee class.**
Employee object has no args constructor
Say `Map<String, Employee> empMap` is my map object.
How can I instantiate object in place and set values and put it in map.

```
Map<String, Employee> mymap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("employee_key", () -> {
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.setSalary(10000);
    return e;
});
```

This shows error : Target type of lambda conversion must be an interface.

What i **dont** want to do:

```
myMap.put("employee_key", getEmployee(1000));
private Employee getEmployee(int salary){
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.setSalary(salary);
    return e;
}
```

In short, I am expecting in place instantiation and assignment while putting it as value in a map **without using extra method** .

Comment: change your Employee so that `setSalary` returns `this`; then you could write `myMap.put("employee_key", new Employee().setSalary(10000)`. Or look at Lombok that has methods for that

Comment: @Eugene OP says there is no possibility for him to change the class `Employee`. I have overlooked that at first, too. Second sentence: *I have no modification access to Employee class*

Comment: @deHaar in such a case create a static factory method that would create an Employee : `static Employee createIt(int salary) {Employee e = new Employee(); e.setSalary(salary); return e; }` and use that.

Comment: @Eugene i have no modification access and all setters are of void return! Also, no extra method. Everything to be done in place.

Comment: @divyajain in such a case, that is _your problem_ and your limitation. why does that matter "in place"?

Comment: If getEmployee() method can return an employee object, then there must be something that can return the employee object and allow everything inplace.
More than a limitation, its kind of POC i am trying to do.

Comment: then your POC has just failed; there might be some weird ways to do this (I can't think of one), but losing time on this, is useless IMO.

Comment: "without using extra method" Even in your first example, you **are** using a method. It's a method of a lambda but it's still a method.

Comment: I looked up all possible meanings of POC, but didn’t find any that could explain your artificial limitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with deHaar that simply using `put`, with or without a convenience method, is likely your best option. However what you've asked for can be fairly nicely achieved using the `compute` method:

```
myMap.compute("employee_key", (k, v) -> {
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.setSalary(10000);
    return e;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The wish to `put` a key-value pair into a `Map` while instantiating the value object and setting the value of a class attribute

- without the possibility of providing a parametrized constructor,
- without using an extra method and
- without creating a factory class

seems nearly impossible to be fulfilled or ugly/uncommon, at least.

The shortest (but not in-place) solution I can think of is an instatiation plus a setter plus putting the object into the `Map`, like this:

```
Map<String, Employee> myMap = new HashMap<>();
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setSalary(10000);
myMap.put("employee_key", employee);
```

This is basically a three-liner, which even beats your non-working lambda by one line less.